# How to set ADO pipeline to fail if stage took more time to execute than n seconds

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

As title says, is there a way that I could set a condition for stage in ADO pipeline that for example if stage took 20 seconds to complete, but I set the threshold for execution to be 10 second, and in that case pipeline should fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at the stage level, and not in seconds.

You can set a timeout for [Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job?view=azure-pipelines) and [Steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps?view=azure-pipelines) but the timeout is in minutes so the shortest duration you could have would be 1 minute

```
steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
  timeoutInMinutes: 1
```